# Pass the parameter at the time of msi installation in chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want to install the msi package. At the time of installation i want to change the installation directory. So I need to pass my custom path in windows_package.

can anybody tell me how to achieve it.

Regards,
Ramadurai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `options` property. An example from the Chef documentation:

```
windows_package 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable' do
  source 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/B/B/6BB661D6-A8AE-4819-B79F-236472F6070C/vcredist_x86.exe'
  installer_type :custom
  options '/Q'
end
```